# Does NASA, or any other group, have any plans to directly explore caves on Mars or the moon?

Tags: mars, the-moon, future-missions, caves

The importance of Martian caves for life past and present, volatiles being trapped, and for future habitats would seem to put their exploration high on the list but I don't see any missions to do so.  Same with the moon minus the life part.

Comment: Yes, they have been attempting to do this for years, however, it is very difficult to set up any kind of research outposts for study of Mars or the Moon,for obvious reasons. See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caves_of_Mars_Project for a start

Comment: For those looking at this site on a desktop (or other more capable system), here's the regular Wikipedia link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caves_of_Mars_Project for the page @MarkKirby cited.

Comment: I expanded the question to any other group, not just NASA.  It appears they've studied the prospect of putting habitats in the martian caves and sealing them to use as well, plus other interesting research.  (Argon as buffer gas in crickets and mice, wireless communication in limestone caves, etc.)  But no plans for unmanned probes that I could find.

Comment: https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/637136main_Whittaker_Presentation.pdf has some references at the end that may lead to answers.

Comment: Wow, that was a very cool and detailed pdf on a proposed cave exploration! At least someone has thought it through extensively.